# neo4j truncating a database opened via batchinserter (bonus : embedded)

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

```
val db_loc = "/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.0.0/libexec/data/graph.db"
val inserter = BatchInserters.inserter(db_loc)
```

I [see](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/2.0.0/apidocs/org/neo4j/unsafe/batchinsert/BatchInserters.html#batchDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileSystemAbstraction,%20java.util.Map%29) there is a form of getting the inserter that takes a config map. Is there a property for me to set to get the database to truncate itself ? if not how do I truncate the db via the API ?

Deleting the db directly pre-opening seems a tad vulgar.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go vulgar. Or use `FileUtils.deleteRecursively(File(db_loc))`

You should still use the config variant as you will have to configure your [mmio settings for the batch-inserter](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/configuration-io-examples.html#configuration-batchinsert) and also remember to set the heap large enough to accomodate mmio + normal heap usage (this is special in batch-insertion).

See also: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/batchinsert.html